# How can I find likely occurrences of substrings inside another string?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Say I have a collection of strings:

- constitution
- abracadabra
- refrigerator
- stackoverflow

And I have a "damaged" sentence where significant substrings of those strings can be found, in no particular order or specific count. The words are also not necessarily clearly-separated.

What algorithm could help me find the most likely occurrences of the strings from the collection in the damaged sentence?

Here's an example input:

> xbracadabrqbonstitution ibracadabrefrigeratos obracadabri xtackoverflotefrigeratos

From that input, I would expect to be able to reconstruct this array of known words:

> ['abcracadabra', 'constitution', 'abracadabra', 'refrigerator', 'abracadabrea', 'stackoverflow', 'refrigerator']

The sentences are pretty short (usually 5-6 words), so I can afford memory- and power-hungry algorithms. Also, the damage is always confined to the few first and last characters of each word; the middle is always correct (this is why I'm looking for large substrings).

Any idea? Since the words aren't clearly separated, plain edit distance doesn't do it.

Comment: How many words will be in your dictionary? How big can each word be?

Comment: @MAK, my dictionary is quite small (15-20 words) and the words themselves are quite small too (5-7 characters long). I used longer words to illustrate my problem and make it obvious that the middle part stays intact. The sentence can have a length varying between 5 and 20 words (once restituted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are very few words in your dictionary, and the words themselves are quite small, I would simply try looking for all possible substrings of each word in the dictionary. Of course, it is meaningless to look for substrings of size 0 or 1, you will probably want to have a lower threshold on the size of the word.

For each substring, you can simply look for it in the sentence, and if it occurs you can mark it as being possibly part of the sentence. For speed you might want to do do the search within the sentence in O(n) (e.g. using [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or [Rabin Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm))

Here's a simple hack of the idea in Python (using brute force string matching):

```
d=["constitution","abracadabra","refrigerator","stackoverflow"]

def substring_match(word,sentence,min_length):
    for start in xrange(0,len(word)):
        for end in xrange(start+min_length,len(word)):
            substr=word[start:end+1]
            if substr in sentence:
                return True
    return False

def look_for_words(word_dict,sent_word):
    return [word for word in word_dict if substring_match(word,sent_word,5)]

def look(word_dict,sentence):
    ret=[]
    for word in sentence.split():
        ret.extend(look_for_words(word_dict,word))
    return ret

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "\n".join(look(d,"xbracadabrqbonstitution ibracadabrefrigeratos obracadabri xtackoverflotefrigeratos"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the size of your problem stated, I'm not going to worry about optimizing this solution at all, since anything short of exponential will run instantly.  I'll only give you an algorithm that I'm pretty sure can give as correct an answer as you could expect for a semi fuzzy problem like this.  Then we can work on optimizing it.

First, you need any heuristic function f, which takes a word w and returns the closest word or no match.

Then you just generate the set of all possible w's within your string.  In the worst case, that means taking the set of all strings of length 1, then of length 2, then of length 3 up to the length of you string.  The total number of w's generated this way would be around (n * n-1) / 2

If you're worried about speed, you can set a max word length, and the cost of generating ws drops back down to linear in the length of your string.

Take your set of words and dump each one in turn into f, you can use any heuristic you want to determine which words are chosen as real words from your dictionary, or what to do when your chosen words overlap.  A simple implementation might sort all the words by start letter index, and any time f returns a match, skip letters until the end of the selected word.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to find words with minimal distance to the words in your dictionary (you define the tolerance).

Good luck!

Comment: Edit distance is choking on words that were merged. :/

Comment: I can find an edge-case for any algorithm to choke on merged words. How to handle this cases is up-to you. The question is how many merged words would you expect? Anyway, I came across this library http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/spell/JaccardDistance.html that takes in account overlapping and calculates the distance based on token overlap. Hope it helps...

Comment: _Most_ of my words are merged; this is not an edge case in my situation, and therefore I'm looking for an algorithm that can deal with that. I'm asking the question precisely because the algorithms I know for dealing with string differences fail in this context. The Jaccard distance looked promising, but I read the Wikipedia description and I'm not sure it really deals with that situation.

Comment: Well, seems like no OOTB solution for your problem (at least not that I am aware of)... How about applying distance in order to find the closest candidates from your dictionary and then check them one-by-one (brute force)?